# Applying Groupby with an np.where function to detect a pattern

Tags: pandas, numpy

I've made a function that finds a pattern in a series in a dataframe using np.where. The function finds a series of three <0 values where each is lower than the previous. If the 4th value is higher than the 3rd, the function returns 1.
The function works but I need to use groupby to apply it to all the names in the table.

Here is the working code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
def PFunc1():
    val = np.where((
        (df1['Score'].shift(+3)<0) &
        (df1['Score'].shift(+1)<0) &
        (df1['Score'].shift(+2) < df1['Score'].shift(+3)) & 
        (df1['Score'].shift(+1) < df1['Score'].shift(+2)) & 
        (df1['Score'] > df1['Score'].shift(+1))),1,0)
    return val

df1 = pd.DataFrame()
df1['Name'] = ['A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A',
               'B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B']
df1['Score'] = np.random.randint(-4,3,df1.shape[0])
df1['Pattern'] = PFunc1()
df1.head(50)
```

When I run the below I get the error: TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'
Applying the same with a Lambda function results in Nans.

```
df1['Pattern2'] = df1.groupby('Name')['Score'].apply(PFunc1())
```

Is this possible with np.where or is a different approach needed?
Many thanks

Comment: `PFunc1()` is a boolean array the size of a column.  Verify that.  What does `groupby.apply` expect?  I haven't used that, so you have to  study the docs yourself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The function works but I need to use groupby to apply it to all the names in the table.

It looks like you aren't performing an aggregation; you're performing an item-by-item transformation.  Therefore, don't use `GroupBy.apply()`, use [`GroupBy.transform()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.transform.html).

The transforming function needs to accept a `Series` as input, so you should modify `PFunc1` to accept an argument.

Also, `PFunc1` can be slightly streamlined:

- It doesn't require `np.where`
- You don't need to check if `scores.shift(+1) < 0`

  - (If the first item is less than 0 and the next two items are even less than the first, then there's no need to check if they are also less than 0.)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

def PFunc1(scores):
    return (
        (scores.shift(+3)<0) &
        (scores.shift(+2) < scores.shift(+3)) &
        (scores.shift(+1) < scores.shift(+2)) &
        (scores > scores.shift(+1))
    ).astype(int)


df1 = pd.DataFrame()
df1['Name'] = ['A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A','A',
               'B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B','B']
df1['Score'] = np.random.randint(-4,0,df1.shape[0])

# Process all Scores without respect to Name
df1['Pattern'] = PFunc1(df1['Score'])

# Process Scores for each Name independently
df1['Pattern2'] = df1.groupby('Name')['Score'].transform(PFunc1)
```

Comment: Thank you Sir this is a big help and also explains transform.